# How to check if a list of custom object contains all elements from another list having same properties?

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of cities having below properties.

City - cityId, cityName, state, zipCode

```
City city1 = new City(1,"Lucknow","UP",123);
City city2 = new City(2,"Kanpur","UP",1234);
City city3 = new City(3,"Allahabad","UP",12345);
City city4 = new City(4,"Agra","UP",1232);

List<City> cityList = new ArrayList();
cityList.add(city1);
cityList.add(city2);
cityList.add(city3);
cityList.add(city4);
```

I have another list of Students and Student also has a property with name City.

Student -> id, name, cityName

```
Student s1 = new Student(111,"Sachin","Allahabad");
Student s2 = new Student(222,"Anil","Agra");

List<Student> studList = new ArrayList();
studList.add(s1);
studList.add(s2);
```

I have to check if cityList(cityName) contains all the cities from studentList(cityName).

In above scenario it should return true.

If I add another student object with cityName("Delhi"), it should return false as it is not present in cityList.

Can someone help me to understand how to implement above scenario efficiently using Java 8 ?

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you can do is,

1. Create a master set of cities;

   Set cities = cityList.stream().map(city -> city. getCityName().toUpperCase()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
2. Create another set for student cities

   Set studentCities = studList.stream().map(student -> student.getCityName().toUpperCase()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
3. check if master set contains all student cities :

   private boolean containsAll(cities, studentCities) {
   return cities.containsAll(studentCities);
   }

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially a set intersection operation, which can be accomplished as a short-circuited operation as follows

```
Set<String> cities = cityList.stream().map(City::name).collect(Collectors.toSet());
boolean result = !studList.stream().
    map(Student::city)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet())
    .stream()
    .anyMatch(Predicate.not(cities::contains));
```

Answer (score 1):

First, put all the city names in a `Set<String>` as follows.  Using a set is much more efficient than using a `List` for lookup.

```
Set<String> cityNames = cityList.stream()
        .map(City::getCityName).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Then simply stream the student list and map the results of seeing if all the city names are in the `cityNames` list.

```
boolean result = studList.stream()
             .map(Student::getCityName)
             .allMatch(cityNames::contains);

System.out.println(result);
```

Note: First override equals() and hashCode() in your city class.  This is just good Java practice.  Then make your `cityList` a `citySet` for efficiency. Then if your student class had the City object instead of the city name all you would need is the following:

```
boolean result = studList.stream()
                .map(Student::getCity)
                .allMatch(citySet::contains);
```

Answer (score -1):

I made a function that does it, but I feel like there is a more efficient solution.

```
    private static boolean checkStatus(List<Student> studentList, List<City> cityList) {
        List<String> cityNames = cityList.stream()
        .map(City::getCityName)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return studentList.stream()
        .map(Student::getCityName)
        .allMatch(cityNames::contains);
    }
```

If for instance your student class had a City field not a cityName then this would be a solution:

```
    private static boolean checkStatus(List<Student> studentList, List<City> cityList) {
        return studentList.stream().map(Student::getCity).allMatch(cityList::contains);
    }
```

A nice one-liner.

You could go further with this, but I feel that this is good enough for millions of students and cities. You should not worry too much about performance with this method (if your student class has a `City` field).

Edit:

Make sure you override both `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods in City class if you wish to use the second approach as WJS noted.

Comment: Unfortunately, this latter example won't work unless the `City` class overrides `equals()` and `hashCode()` which we can't be certain of.

Comment: You should collect city names to a `Set` instead of to a `List`. This is the exact situation when you need to think about performance in advance